# quiero obtener el nombre de mi usuario para poder pasarlo por pantalla en mi app pero al parecer lo esta devolviendo null

Tags: java

```
    //initiate the firebase
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //check if user sign out
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Iniciar.class));
    }
    // get the phone of current user
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String [] parts = email.split("a");
    ownPhone = parts[0];

  

    // get the database reference of current user
    DatabaseReference mCurrentUser = mPhoneNo.child(ownPhone);
    DatabaseReference mFirstName = mCurrentUser.child("firstName");
    DatabaseReference mBalance = mCurrentUser.child("balanceAmount");

    balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(listFrame, listIcon) {
    });
```

** Y este es parte de mi codigo**

**Y donde me marca el error, ahi estoy tratando de obtener el nombre de usuario para que salga a un costado en la app, cuando el user ya este el home activity**`

```
//retrieve the Name of User from database in realtime
   mFirstName.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String tvname = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i(TAG,tvname);
            tranUserNameText.setText(tvname);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Toast.makeText(Transaction.this, "Cannot find your name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });










java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:176)
at com.example.vepago14.Transaction$3.onDataChange(Transaction.java:153)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7542)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

**Y este es el error que me sale, dice que en " Log.i(TAG,tvname);" se esta devolviendo como null y me saca de la app, y la verdad no se que tengo malo ahi, y en el android studio no me dice exactamente cual es el eror**

Answer (score 0):

a ver si te sirve.

Para obtener el usuario (uid) en Firebase, se usaría:

```
UserRecord usuario = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid);
```

Luego para evaluar si ese usuario es nulo:

```
if(usuario != null){ 
    System.out.println("El usuario actual es: " + userRecord.getUid());
}
else{
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Iniciar.class));
    finish();
}
```